# How does Wells Fargo can detect my right account if I have multiple accounts when I am transferring money?

Tags: money-transfer, online-banking, online-payment, online

I have 4 different bank accounts with 4 different banks. I wanted to transfer money from my account in Wells Fargo to my account in some other bank ONLINE. But I don't see any option to add my other bank's account number and routing number in wells fargo website. I can add the recipient by first name, last name and email or phone number. My question is, how does wells fargo know what is my right bank account among the 3 other bank accounts, by just using my phone number or email? I feel it too confusing.

Comment: I saw a similar question on this website, but that does not answer what if we have multiple bank accounts and if we want to send money to only 1 account by email or phone.

Comment: What transfer system are you using?  If you're not providing the account number and RTN, then you're doing it through some other system - I would guess SurePay?

Comment: yes, it is WF Sure Pay

Comment: Usually the recipient has to pick their account if it is sent to an e-mail has been my experience in Canada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SurePay, the recipient has to register in order to receive funds.  They will select where the money is deposited.  If you are both the sender and the receiver, I don't know if the system will get confused or not - If it will work at all though, you'll ultimately need to enter the information for the receiving account.

The point of sure pay is to avoid the receiving party needing to give the *sender* their account information.  The banking system still gets the account information explicitly from both sides.

EDIT:  This post also provides relevant and more detailed information: [How does Wells Fargo use my phone number to find my Bank of America account?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36179/how-does-wells-fargo-use-my-phone-number-to-find-my-bank-of-america-account)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the answer either by your answer or by the link you provided in your answer. I already know that link. But my question is, for example if I have bank accounts with BoA, Wells Fargo, Citi Bank, US Bank, and I want to transfer money from my wells fargo account to BoA using WF Sure Pay, HOW DOES WELLS FARGO KNOWS that I want to transfer money to BoA account.

Comment: Whoever is the recipient - whether that's you or someone else - needs to register. When you register, you'll have to tell them which (specific)account you want to receive money. Your question seems to be based on a premise that WF automatically detects your accounts at various banks, and that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

SurePay is not designed to send money from one person to himself.  It is designed to transfer money from one person to *someone else*.

What SurePay does, is allow you to link an account to a name/email/phone number.  Then, when someone else, who's also linked an account to a name/email/phone number, selects your name/email/phone number to send money to, the money is transferred.

```
(your account#/ABA #) -> (your email) <-> (their email) <- (their account#/aba #)
```

This doesn't buy you anything when transferring money to another of your own accounts.  I won't say it's impossible to use SurePay to do so, but it's definitely not *designed* to do so, and may not be permitted.

If you could use it for that purpose, you would have to separately register your two accounts, using a separate email for each, and then use the first email to send to the second email; each will have been tied to a different account, so you'll know which is which.

My suggestion would be to follow Wells Fargo's instructions [here](https://www.wellsfargo.com/help/faqs/transfers/):

> **Can I transfer funds to or from my accounts at another institution?**
>
> > You can transfer money between your Wells Fargo checking and savings accounts and accounts you may have at other U.S. financial institutions. Wells Fargo gives you greater flexibility, convenience, and control to transfer funds where and when you need it. Sign on to Wells Fargo Online and click the Transfers tab to learn more about transferring funds to your account at another financial institution.

As that should give you the official answer, at least.

Comment: OK, Perhaps I want to ask like this. So, what if I want to transfer money to someone using SurePay if that someone has multiple bank accounts with different financial institutions??? How does the system recognizes a particular bank account of that someone from multiple accounts of that someone??????

Comment: And why shouldn't I be that someone?

Comment: I saw your instructions, and I already tried them. If I follow that instructions I can transfer money INTO wells fargo account, but cannot transfer money from wells fargo account.

Comment: @TheGuest If you want to transfer money using SurePay to someone with multiple accounts, it's up to them to associate the correct account with their SurePay ID/email/whatever.  That's the _point_ - you don't know about that detail.  SurePay is not designed as a way to get around paying ACH fees to transfer money between accounts - it's designed as a way to allow you to transfer money to a person without knowing their bank info.

Comment: Yes, I don't about it. That is my question here :)